# View model as dictionary

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I would like to pass my view the following model:

```
Dictionary<Person, Dictionary<Assignment, List<Hours>>>
```

I have a feeling that my approach isnt the best one.
So, what I do is: I run the necessary queries and get:

```
{ Person, Assignment, Hours }
```

anonymous objects

```
    if Person in dictionary {
      if Assignment not in inner dictionary { 
          add Assignment
          add Hour
       }
      else {
         add Hour
       }
    }
    else { 
       add Person; 
       add Assignment
       add Hour
}
```

To display in a table:
[image]

Everything works, but is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is and what you're trying to do. Can you be more specific? Please show your code, not pseudo-code.

Comment: everything works fine, but i am wondering if that is the best way to populate my view Model

Comment: i don't know how else you'd go about it.  Your logic seems fine

Comment: It's hard to judge your method of populating your view model if you don't show us the actual code. If it works, it works. Don't try to fix problems that don't exist.

Comment: It could probably be done with a Linq query but the way the Linq query 'reads' might be a little bit less straightforward -- i.e. slightly challenging to understand by just reading it.

Comment: It all depends on how your view will use the data. That's pretty complex data - how _will_ your view use it?

Comment: Got any `td`'s in there? Really, you're showing the output of your view (partially), without showing the code of your view which produces the output.

Comment: @JohnSaunders its lots of code. Trying to keep it simple. Yes there are td's. I am doing [foreach KeyValuePair] to loop the dictionaries

Comment: Here's the deal: I am unable to imagine a reason to use a model like that. You need to help my imagination (and maybe those of others reading this).

Comment: @JohnSaunders maybe i am not using the right model. I have updated the question with want I want to show on screen. Should i change my model?

Comment: Why don't you do some processing before it gets to the view model and create a model to hold Person, Assignment, Hours in a broken down format?

Comment: @PaulZahra what model would be best practice for my view?

Comment: @den It could be done multiple ways but a simple class like Public Class PersonnelAssignment {public Person PersonDetails { get; set; } public List<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }} and Assignments would have Hours within it as I guess that hours is a facet of Assignment. Then in your viewmodel you would have a List<PersonnelAssignments>

Comment: @PaulZahra isnt that the same? you just have replaced Dictionaries with Lists

Comment: @den the same in a logical sense... in a sense of not passing around a convoluted data structure but instead a more logical, maintainable and readable data structure, they are not the same - oh and of course it would simplify the view.

Comment: @den: start by creating a view as simple HTML. Then break it into repeating sections and factor the repeat into the view model.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
List<Tuple<Person,Assignment,Hours>>
```

instead of two dictionaries. I find this makes records with more than two types easier to handle.